# If someone hospitalized on erev Shabbat is then asked/required to sign a release form during Shabbat, what is to be done?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If someone is hospitalized on erev Shabbos, and asked/required to sign a release form upon the conclusion of his time there, should this be signed with a shinui?

Comment: Why can't one stay and wait until after Shabbos to sign?

Comment: @GershonGold let's assume that isn't the ideal scenario due to having "muktzeh" (cash/wallet, phone, etc.), no provisions for seudas, no siddur, etc.

Comment: I'm confused regarding this scenario. The items that you listed in your last comment are not even *safek pikuach nefesh*. When I was in a hospital during Shabbat, and all procedures were done, etc. the hospital understood that I could not leave until after Shabbat was over. All forms were signed Mot. Shabbat. I don't see that there is any other option. Can you edit in some additional info?

Comment: VTC as unclear...

Comment: "upon the conclusion of his time there" are you saying the hospital kicks him out on Shabbat and says, "Sign this form now, b/c we must release you now. If you don't sign now, we're calling the FBI"? In U.S., a patient can walk out of a hospital without signing a form. I've done it, and no one ever came after me and sued me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signing one's name with ink is generally a biblical prohibition which is only waived in cases of *safek pikuach nefashoth* (risk of loss of life). Where it does not at all increase this risk, a shinui (abnormal implementation) is employed to avoid the biblical prohibition. However, signing with even a halachically valid *shinui* ("abnormal" has to be legally defined) is still rabbincally prohibited and is not allowed just because of inconveniences. Nonetheless, there are often specific leniencies to avoid major inconveniences (*shaat hadechak*; e.g., at times, *shvut d'shvut* [a type of double Rabbinic level of prohibition]) which generally require consulting a halachik authority.

Comment: I accepted this answer, but perhaps you could comment on whether or not the examples listed in the original question could be considered a "major inconvenience (e.g no food, no siddur, etc.)?"

Comment: Sources would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about America but in Israel - there is a network of community ER's called Terem - tipul refuee meyadi - so you can walk to Terem (we are close to one in Modiin) get emergency treatment Erev Shabat and be released later that night.   This is not a theoretical use case since it is a neighborhood ER and if you are not a choleh sheyesh bo sakana (in which they would keep you there) - you (or one of your children) might be released on Shabat.

The solution is trivial - they show you the form and you don't sign.